# Visual Studio can find the definition of an identifier via "Go To Definition", but compiler throws an "identifier not found" (CS3861)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

By right clicking

```
int retVal = pn_Plaus_SDB1xxx_V820(sdbBuffer);
```

in a cpp file of PNIO_SDB_Plausib_Console.vcxproj and selecting *Go To Definition,* Visual Studio 2017 is able to find the following definition in a .cpp file in *PN_CPP_SDB1xxx_Plausib_V820.vcxproj* of the same solution:

```
UINT32 EXPORT pn_Plaus_SDB1xxx_V820(BYTE* in_sdb_Data)
{
    return pn_SDB_Plausib_Controller(in_sdb_Data, 0, 0);
}
```

Building the complete solution however throws an

```
Error   C3861   'pn_Plaus_SDB1xxx_V820': identifier not found
```

for the exact same statement.

Why can VS2017 find the definition and why can't the compiler? What is missing?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is only aware of the specific file it's compiling, including its headers.
The IDE is searching through the entire solution for a definition.

You need to `#include` the header that contains the declaration of the function.
(You can usually find out which one that is by using "Go To Declaration" instead.)

Comment: I have added the header now, and VS2017 is now able to find the declaration via "Go To Declaration", which did not work before. That did not fix the compiler error, however.

Comment: If the compiler finds the header, that *should* work. (You did `#include` the header in the file that won't compile, right? Silly question, but we've all made that mistake.)

Comment: Absolutely. And if the header could not be located, the include statement would already throw an error. Which of the many log files can I use to analyse the error further?

Comment: Mysterious... There aren't namespaces involved or anything like that? Or more than one header with the same name, and your projects have different include paths? If you preprocess the file, is the function declaration there?

Comment: How do I preprocess the file?

Comment: Right-click the file, open Properties, go to Preprocessor, enable "Preprocess to a File". This creates a preprocessed file with an ".i" suffix in your output directory.